# How to restore login screen to Ubuntu's default?

Tags: 20.04, themes, login-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I had been using Big Sur GTK theme (https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme) for a long time and recently I decided to go back to Ubuntu's default look, as my transition from Mac is over. I managed to remove the theme from most places, but I still haven't figured out how to return the login screen to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick uninstall

- uninstall Gtk themes: `./install.sh -r`
- uninstall GDM theme: sudo `./tweaks.sh -g -r`
- uninstall Firefox theme: `./tweaks.sh -f -r`
- uninstall Dash-to-dock theme: `./tweaks.sh -d -r`
- uninstall Flatpak Gtk themes: `./tweaks.sh -F -r`
- uninstall Snap Gtk themes: `./tweaks.sh -s -r`

Comment: Thanks for  your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Drop next command and select up **gdm3** when pop up window comes out to rollback Ubuntu's default.

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

At less worked for me, I had Plasma's default manager set (**sddm**).

[Install Plasma on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-kde-plasma-desktop-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/)